# ¿Cómo puedo señalar cuando aparece un valor por primera vez en un datatable?

Tags: r, datatables, contador

Tengo un datatable que tiene años y clientes, lo que quiero hacer es crear una nueva variable que me diga si el cliente es nuevo en el año.

```
dt <- data.table(c('2011','2011','2011',
                   '2012','2012','2012',
                   '2013','2013','2013',
                   '2014','2014','2014',
                   '2015','2015','2015'),
                 c('A1','A2','A3',
                   'A1','A2','B2',
                   'B2','C1','A3',
                   'C1','B2','A3',
                   'B2','C1','C2'))
colnames(dt) <- c('Year','Cliente')
```

Los datos quedan de esta manera:

```
    Year Cliente
 1: 2011      A1
 2: 2011      A2
 3: 2011      A3
 4: 2012      A1
 5: 2012      A2
 6: 2012      B2
 7: 2013      B2
 8: 2013      C1
 9: 2013      A3
10: 2014      C1
11: 2014      B2
12: 2014      A3
13: 2015      B2
14: 2015      C1
15: 2015      C2
```

Ahora quiero crear una nueva variable que me diga si el cliente es nuevo, es decir, sino ha aparecido en años anteriores.
Por ejemplo, el B2 es nuevo en 2012 y el C1 para el 2013.
No se por donde comenzar, toda ayuda será de agradecer.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer en primer lugar es ver cual es el primer año por cada cliente mediante una agrupación:

```
primeras_ocurrencias <- dt[, head(.SD, 1), by=Cliente]
primeras_ocurrencias$primer <- TRUE
primeras_ocurrencias 

   Cliente Year primer
1:      A1 2011   TRUE
2:      A2 2011   TRUE
3:      A3 2011   TRUE
4:      B2 2012   TRUE
5:      C1 2013   TRUE
6:      C2 2015   TRUE
```

La columna agregada `primer` nos servirá en el próximo paso que es un `merge` de las dos tablas, más particularmente lo que se conoce como `left join`:

```
merge(dt,primeras_ocurrencias, all.x=TRUE)

    Year Cliente primer
 1: 2011      A1   TRUE
 2: 2011      A2   TRUE
 3: 2011      A3   TRUE
 4: 2012      A1     NA
 5: 2012      A2     NA
 6: 2012      B2   TRUE
 7: 2013      A3     NA
 8: 2013      B2     NA
 9: 2013      C1   TRUE
10: 2014      A3     NA
11: 2014      B2     NA
12: 2014      C1     NA
13: 2015      B2     NA
14: 2015      C1     NA
15: 2015      C2   TRUE
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no tenia ni idea del tema de la agrupación y estaba pensando en hacer cosas más complicadas.